# Why is limitTo not working with orderBy in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am a bit new to AngularJS and am having problems getting more than one filter to work together. I have a collection of ~100 Project objects. I want to select the 10 most recent "projects" ascending. I have the following code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="project in projects | orderBy:'Timestamp' | limitTo:10 ">
  <td>{{project.Poster}}</td>
  <td>{{project.Message}}</td>
</tr>
```

The above displays all projects ordered by Timestamp, **but does not limit number of projects displayed**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it. I've copied it [into a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HZgxA2ZoIFdiVb48qIiJ?p=preview) to be sure, but it works. Can you add some additional context info to the plunker?

Comment: Wow, thanks for the work on that. Is there any difference when loading the collection from Firebase:
.factory('Projects', function($firebase, fbURL) {
  return $firebase(f);
})